# uploadify works on local but not on the server:"undefined" instead of browse button

Tags: java, jquery, struts, uploadify

I'm recently using uploadify 2.1.0 with Java(struts) and When I run the project on localhost server, everything seems perfect but when upload it on server(windows server 2008), the browse button goes and an "undefined" text showed instead.I tried to install updated Adobe Flash Player(v.14) on the server but nothing changed.
here is initialization script:

```html
<link href="uploadify/uploadify.css" rel="stylesheet">
<script src="uploadify/jquery-1.3.2.min.js"></script>
<script src="uploadify/swfobject.js"></script>
<script src="uploadify/jquery.uploadify.v2.1.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#uploadify').uploadify({
            'uploader': 'uploadify/uploadify.swf',
            'script': 'upload.do',
            'cancelImg': 'uploadify/cancel.png',
            'onComplete': function(event, queueID, fileObj, response, data) {
               $("#fileId").val(response);
                return false;
            }
        });
        $('#upload').click(function() {
            $('#uploadify').uploadifyUpload();
            return false;
        });
    });
</script>
```

and usage of it:`

```
                    <input id="uploadify" type="file">
                    <a id="upload" href="#">Upload</a>
```

Comment: Have you checked to make sure the js files are being served ok on production?

Comment: I've looked console (using developer tools) and did not see any 404 error for js files